# Resize UITableView programmatically inside a UIScrollView and avoid AutoLayout Constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, resize, autolayout

I have a UIScrollView that contains some components inside. One of these controls is a UITableView, which is used to display a list of schedules for a movie, at most would be about 7 rows.

I set the UITableView to not allow movement of any kind, and programmatically change its size to fit to its content and also increase the content size of UIScrollView so that it can scroll smoothly.

As soon as the view is displayed on the screen, resizing works correctly, but when I scroll the UIScrollView to see below, the UITableView returns to its previous size.

See the next image: http://d.pr/i/rKzb

I am using Storyboard AutoLayout for design the interface, and the UITableView has the following restrictions:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GowOG.png

Here is how I'm resizing the controls:

```
- (void) resizeViews {
    //
    // Synopsis
    //
    CGRect synopsisNewFrame = [Utilities adjustLabel:_movieSynopsis frameForText:_movieSynopsis.text];
    [_movieSynopsis setFrame:  synopsisNewFrame];


    //
    // Schedules
    //
    CGRect schedulesNewFrame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                                      _movieSynopsis.frame.origin.y + _movieSynopsis.frame.size.height + 4,
                                      self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                      self.tableView.contentSize.height);

    [self.tableView setFrame: schedulesNewFrame];

    //
    // Scroll View
    //

    CGSize scrollSize = CGSizeMake(292, self.tableView.frame.origin.y + self.tableView.frame.size.height + 10);

    [_scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self.tableView setContentSize: scrollSize];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

}
```

And here is where I'm calling the resizeView (in the ViewController):

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self resizeViews];
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this to happen?

I'm pretty sure the problem is the constraints that have the UITableView.

Let me suggest solution to prevent this from happening, while using AutoLayout.

Thanks in advance for your help.

(Sorry I can't post images)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue today. As you suspected, it is the AutoLayout problem. I'm not sure how to solve it properly right now. But if you disable the AutoLayout, it would be fine. For this purpose, you can open the XIB file select File Inspector tab, then remove the check before Use AutoLayout

Answer (score 0):

Since your using AutoLayout, you'll need to adjust your height constraint.

See this post [Change UITableView height dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your viewDidAppear if you want to set the contentSize of the scrollView that matches what you've done in the Storyboard.

```
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
```