# Adjust UITableView height dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

How can I adjust the `UITableView` height dynamically? Let's say I have 3 rows and each row has a height of 65. When a new row is added to the `UITableView` i want it to adjust it's height dynamically to fit the new row. And vice versa when a row is deleted to shrink.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14228015/1129959 but it's too complicated and not obvious at all

Comment: Show your codes please.

Comment: @ŁukaszTomaszewski not a duplicate. cell height vs table height

Comment: @Legnus Will you consider to have `UITableView` occupy the full height of the page, instead of dynamically changing the height? This is the most common usage. and this question is unrelated to [tag:xcode5]

Comment: All are in hurry to give answer without reading whole question.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the other is talking about UITableViewCell height, I'm talking about UITableView height. and @Raptor I do not have any code yet to show. just a simple tableview that i want it to have a dynamic height for the number of rows

Comment: @Raptor I can't do that since it happens to be at the end of a UIScrollView, and i need to adjust the ScrollView height based on the UITableView height

Comment: Interesting. `UITableView` itself contains a scrollview. Double scrolling is not suggested in User Experience.

Comment: @Raptor The user is not allowed to scroll in my tableview since i disabled the scrolling

Comment: Weird structure, but if you insist, that's okay. I suggest to use a simple `UITableView` only

Answer (score 2):

Edit : Misread

The thing depends on the (height of table cell row * number of rows in table) as the tableview.frame.size.height.

Well I would suggest something like this..

```
-(void)correctHeight
{

    //Note : if all cells are having common value
    CGFloat heightOfCell=[table rowHeight];

    CGFloat expectedHeightOfTable=0;
    for (int i=0; i< [table numberOfSections]; i++) {
        //header section
        CGFloat heightOfHeaderView=[table headerViewForSection:i].frame.size.height;
        expectedHeightOfTable = expectedHeightOfTable +heightOfHeaderView;

        //content section
         expectedHeightOfTable = expectedHeightOfTable + heightOfCell*[table numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    }
    [table setFrame:CGRectMake(table.frame.origin.x, table.frame.origin.y, table.frame.size.width,expectedHeightOfTable)];


}
```

This will consider header  and each row  content and all value populated prormatically..So dont need to add some hardcoded values

Comment: OP is asking to change UITableView's height

Comment: Thank you i tried it, the height of the tableview is changing while debugging but visually it's always the same height

Comment: that is because its supeview is remaining the same

Answer (score 1):

The tableview height can be set by,

```
[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
```

But for example if u set the height as 150 and you 5 rows of height 60px using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: then the tableView will become scrollable as UITableView is a sub class of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, Weird structure, but if you insist, that's okay. I suggest to use a simple `UITableView` only.

Assume you have `IBOutlet` to `UITableView` and `UIScrollView`...

Before adding codes in `viewWillAppear`, add:

```
float cellHeight = 65.0f;
int numberOfCells = 3;
```

In `- (void)viewWillAppear:animated`, add the following after `[super viewWillAppear:animated]`:

```
// remember fill the table with data using UITableViewDataSource's functions first
// refresh UITableView data
[tableView reloadData];
// resize UITableView
[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, cellHeight * numberOfCells)];
// make UIScrollView the same size as UITableView
[scrollView setContentSize:tableView.frame.size];
[scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
// remember to lock tableView's scrolling, either in code / Interface Builder
[tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

And in `UITableViewDelegate`'s delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return numberOfCells;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return cellHeight;
}
```

Last, if you wish to double verify if any of the table cell is out of sight, you can use:

```
- (NSArray *)visibleCells
```

Comment: You missed header height.

Comment: Yes, if header is set visible (since header is hidden in most cases). Really depends on OP's layout.

Comment: Thank U i tried it, the height of the tableview is changing while debugging but visually it's always the same height

Comment: My bad. After looking up documentation, the codes should be put inside `viewWillAppear:animated` instead of `viewDidLoad` in order to make dynamic changes on table view size