# Dynamically changing UITableView height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

In my app I have a `UITableView` with a `UIView` placed above its frame:

```
 -----------
|  UIView   |
 -----------
|           | 
|           |
|UITableView|
|           |
|           |
 -----------
```

When I scroll the `tableView` up the `UIView` is pushed up out of the screen and when the contents of the `tableView` are scrolled down the `UIView` gets pushed back into the screen. All the movement of the `UIView` happens with the same speed as the user scrolls. So if the user scroll 10px the UIView is only moved 10px.

The problem I am having is the resizing of the `tableView`. I want it to resize according to the y-position of the UIView so that there is never any space between then.

The moving of the `UIView` is working perfectly but the resizing of the `tableView` not at all. I really freezes up the main thread and it is really edgy.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    Some code for moving the UIView...

    UpdateFrameY(_tableViewController.tableView, diff);
    UpdateFrameHeightOnDiff(_tableViewController.tableView, diff);
}
```

Is there a better way I can do this?
I am actually trying to copy this behavior from the FB app. It works really smoothly there.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change UITableView height dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically)

Comment: I'd like to know more details, like if the cells height is changed with the table hight update. A sample project would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the uitableview heigth. Just change its content insets and place your UIView over the UITableView (so the UIView and the UITableView will have the same frame origin); you will have some performance improvements.

Comment: I actually tried this but I had a problem with my content insets because I am using a UIRefreshControl inside my UITableViewController. This always messes with the content insets.

Comment: you can try not to animate the content insets. just make it fixed. When the UITableView will scroll to the top most cell, the top UIView will always have its biggest frame