# Change height of UITableView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and I'd like to change its height programmatically depending on the number of cells contained in it.

Can you help me?

Comment: What you are trying to do is wrong. UITableView will automatically adjust its content size (the scrolling area) depending on how many cells it contains (depending on the data source).

Comment: You can do that. In your `numberOfRowsInSection` method change the frame size of your UITableView `self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change UITableView height dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
self.yourTableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,noOfCell*heightOfOneCell);
```

Comment: For anyone wondering...this is the correct answer. Worked for me. Thanks @souvickcse.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe `tableView.contentSize` changes and bind the value to the `frame`, keep in mind you might run into memory issues since table view won't recycle cells

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `sizeToFit` or `sizeThatFits:`?

```
CGRect tFrame = tableView.frame;
tFrame.size.height = MIN([tableView sizeThatFits: CGSizeMake(tFrame.size.width,
                                                             CGFLOAT_MAX)].height,
                         MaximumTableHieght);
tableView.frame = tFrame;
```

Or try this (I don't remember which was working for me).

```
CGRect tFrame = tableView.frame;
tFrame.size.height = MIN(tableView.contentSize.height,
                         MaximumTableHieght);
tableView.frame = tFrame;
```

Comment: Hi unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't even know why...I used the code and nothing happens! Basically I have a scrolling view with an UIImageView on the top and a UITableView on the bottom, with some cells and I want the whole thing to scroll together...but obviously to do that I need to see ALL the cells into the tableView...so, I need to resize it depending by its content. Any ideas?

Comment: try edited second version, I just don't remember which one worked well.