# How to set different height for different rows of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

how can i set different height for different rows of custom ui table view cell in ios?
I am trying to change the height depending upon the how much lines there are in my uitextview which is inside my custom uitableview cell.

I tried setting height like this inside my heightForRowAtIndexPath method but it crashes:

```
PostStreamCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
int lines = cell.txtViewMessage.contentSize.height / cell.txtViewMessage.font.lineHeight;

if(lines < 4)
{
    return 100;
}
else if(lines == 4)
{
    return 100;
}
else{
    return 220;
}
```

Comment: Whats's the crash message ?

Comment: Actually don't tell me, it's probably because you're dividing by zero? Table view cells are created after heightForRorAtIndexPath: so you cell objects will also be nil ? Add a breakpoint and see if cell is nil.

Comment: no the cell is not nil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change UITableView height dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` *because the cell does not exist.* You must retrieve the text by another way without use the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the `text boundingRectWithSize..` for calculating the size for cell itself .

Something like this :

```
 NSString *text = yourTextView.text;
    CGSize size;

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:19], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];
    CGRect fontSizeFor7 = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(525, 500)
                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                          attributes:attributesDictionary
                                             context:nil];
    size = fontSizeFor7.size;

    return size.height +40;
```

Comment: but my uitextview is in custom uitable view cell . how can i access that cell and get size of that uitextview ?

Comment: Ok, Why can't you access the UITextView in the custom cell within the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate.

Comment: if i do that then only 1st row at indexpath is selected

Comment: See there are many ways, you can hold in array of texts before the UItableView, Or just do with conditions accordingly for each rows

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to count 
        int lines 
in 
        viewDidLoad 
method using length of your text field. Then store it in some array and use it values in your
        heightForRowAtIndexPath
method. It should look like this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (myLinesArray[indexPath.row] =< 4)
{
    return 100;
}
else return 220;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the height correctly--however, you probably shouldn't retrieve a cell within `heightForRowAtIndexPath` by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, that is unless your cells are already statically created. A bare-bones implementation of `heightForRowAtIndexPath` (below) doesn't crash, so the problem probably lies elsewhere in your view controller implementation, or elsewhere.

Also noticed that you are dividing by a dynamic value to get the height. Check your PostStreamCell--if the cell object, `txtViewMessage`, or its `font` property is nil, then you will be dividing by 0, and that could be causing the crash.

```
    //Very simple implementation to demo changes in height
    - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (indexPath.row % 2) {
            return 60;
        } else {
            return 44;
        }
    }
```