# ios UITableView after CGAffineTransformMakeScale, how to reset UITableView's height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm try to reset frame's height after zoom, but tableview setFrame does not working. How to reset UITableView's height?

My Code as follows:

```
CGRect rectFrame = self.frame;
CGAffineTransform affineMatrix = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
affineMatrix = CGAffineTransformTranslate(affineMatrix, appSize.width, 120);
self.transform = affineMatrix;
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(rectFrame.origin.x, rectFrame.origin.y, rectFrame.size.width, 900)];
```

self is UITableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                  self.tableView.frame = rectFrame;
                  self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks CarouselMin, I have solved the problem from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically

Comment: You are welcome, thanks for letting me know the link,I'll look into that and try to change the height of tableview.