# Set max height for tableview (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dynamic tableview that increases depending on its content (number of rows within it). However, once at the 11th cell for example, I want the height the frame of the tableview to stop increasing but allow the user to scroll to the bottom of the tableview. Below is the code to make the tableview dynamic.

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    var frame: CGRect = goalsTableView.frame
    frame.size = goalsTableView.contentSize
    goalsTableView.frame = frame
}
```

Comment: Why you try to add the tableView into your scrollView ?

Comment: @HamzaGHAZOUANI With your response, I removed the tableview from the scrollview. This is the main issue i'm having. Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically. Hope that helps

Comment: cheers that just what i needed @HamzaGHAZOUANI