# How to make dynamical height of UITableViewCell which will depend on height of contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have problem with UITableViewCell, I want to make the dynamical height of each cell, I tried code bellow:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] isKindOfClass:[CommentTableViewCell class]]) {
        CommentTableViewCell* cell = (CommentTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell.descriptionText.frame.size.height + 20.0;
    }
   return 44.0;
}
```

But I have error, I have screenshot of this error https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz4j1JqQ0tI4T1Jsb2YxWnBvSTA/view?usp=sharing

Then I use answer of Mohit tomar in this page:
[Change UITableView height dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically)

In result of it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz4j1JqQ0tI4R0t4M0k5THdxNEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please add code where you're creating cell, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Google? Stackoverflow search? Auto layout & `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` are your friends. Example in [Self Sizing Table View Cells](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/07/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html) article and [sample project](https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/tree/master/SelfSize/SelfSize).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: What is the content of each cell?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` get cell height in first,then create cell use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

So you can't use

```
CommentTableViewCell* cell = (CommentTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  return cell.descriptionText.frame.size.height + 20.0;
```

**To get cell height**.
in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`: method ,you must calculate each cell's height for the value of return .

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS ≥ 8 you can use dynamic cell height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Nevertheless, you should also provide `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return eater 44 or the cells approx. height.

Please also verify your constraints. Your second screenshot implies that you don't have a correct bottom constraint or the priorities are incorrect.

The SO-Answer you mentioned is absolutely right, again, only iOS8+

Answer (score 0):

In your tableview's heightForRowAtIndexPath you have to calculate the size of the text and return the "height" parameter of that size.

You can maintain a function as below to calculate the size of the text

```
- (CGSize)heightForText:(NSString *)bodyText
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    CGSize size;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Corbel" size:14.0];
    float iosVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

   rect = [bodyText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(240, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];

    size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    return size;
}
```

and the in your "heightForRowAtIndexPath" use it as :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  CGSize Size = [self heightForText:yourText];
  return Size.height
}
```

This should resize your cell properly