# ViewController with Dynamic TableView Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to build a layout with 5 or 6 views:

1- An header (like a custom navigation bar on top)
2- A tableView with dynamic height( she gets 10 rows by default but the user can click a button(3rd view) where he gets +10 rows (10 + other 10))
3- A view that is a button and when pressed gives more 10 rows to the tableview...

and So on,

My problem is when I try to create with a storyboard and the table view doesn't gain more heigh when gets more rows.

I tried some answers here in stackoverflow but the one that "worked" just "removed" my other views from the viewcontroller.

Can you give me some hint or explanation about the way to do it?

Update:
Is there a way to remove the scroll from the tableview and give her "all the height that she needs"?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically

Comment: that was the one that I've seen and tried Rob's answer and everything below the tableView just gets "ate"