# How to resize the container view with respect to its embedded view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicontainerview

I want to resize the superview with respect to its subview.

The scenario is that I have a scroll view inside it there is a view with different subviews. Within the subviews, there is a ContainerView with embedded view controller. Which have a table view. I want to increase the size of the table view as the cell increases and in the same the increase the height of view- container - view and scroll view, Because the table wont scroll.

i was able to increase the size of the table view following the link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically)

but i am stuck how can i increase the size of the embedded view.
[image]

To elaborate more i am attaching images from a project i am practicing on.

[image]

- Purple is the color of the main view controller.
- Green is scroll view.
- Grey is view inside scroll view.
- Blue is the color of embedded View
  controller.
- Red is the color of table view. but cant be seen on simulator as it has resized according to the number of cells.

  ```
  -(CGSize)sizeForChildContentContainer:(id<UIContentContainer>)container
             withParentContainerSize:(CGSize)parentSize
  {

       //    int height = _containerView.frame.size.height;
       NSLog(@"height of container");
       return _tableView.frame.size;
  }

  -(void)adjustHeightOfTableview

  {

       CGFloat height =  self.tableView.contentSize.height;
       CGFloat maxHeight = self.tableView.superview.frame.size.height -  self.tableView.frame.origin.y;


       // if the height of the content is greater than the maxHeight of
       // total space on the screen, limit the height to the size of the
       // superview.

      if (height > maxHeight)
          height = maxHeight;

      // now set the height constraint accordingly

      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
         self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = height;
         [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

      }];

      [_tableView setNeedsLayout];
      [_tableView layoutIfNeeded];
  }
  ```

In the same way or some thing like that i need to resize the view.
I have searched for some thing similar but i did not got a clear answer, any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you apply autoLayout on the viewcontroller?

Comment: please indent your code when posting so it is readable for other users.

Comment: yes i have added autoLayout

Comment: @Shubhank i have indented the piece of code

Comment: this also looks like a weird requirement. what if the cells grow to 50 and now the embedded VC is just expanding out of the screen ?

Comment: @Shubhank the max number of cells is fixed up to 8 cells, and thats why i need to resize the scroll view so that it expands when the cell increases. and decreases.

Comment: okay, cool. so what are the embedded VC constraints.

Comment: you might also wanna join the chat to explain this more, quite a specific issue to just solve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95993/discussion-between-ios-developer-and-shubhank).