# Dynamic Height for UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, scrollview

i have a tableview with a dynamic changing number of cells. sometimes there are 10, another time more than 20 cells.
This Tableview is on a Viewcontroller, but i have so much content on this tableview, so my tableview and all other content are on a scrollview. now i have a double scroll. on on my scrollview, and another on my tableview and this is quite uncomfortable. so how can i set the height of my tableview dynamically?

Comment: Check the answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14228015/3177007](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14228015/3177007).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Autolayout with storyboard then set constraints of your tableview

```
let Count = CGFloat(dataArray.count)
constraintsTblHeight.constant =  Count*100 //100 is your tablview's cell height
```

other wise increase this height in tablview height

Comment: ok thank you but where do i set the calculated height to my UITableView?