# Dynamic Height of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

How to get the Dynamic Height Of UITableView with Constraints. It will increase the UITableView Height depending upon Number of row without adding Scrollbar in table.
I'm facing problem in adding the TableView in UIViewController and Height of TableView Should not be Statically fixed.

Comment: This question is getting downvotes from people that don't seem to understand it. It was marked as a duplicate of a question that was not related at all. For whoever sees this question, read it carefully before flagging/downvoting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change UITableView height dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223931/change-uitableview-height-dynamically)

Answer (score 5):

The most concise way I've found to do this is by using the `contentSize` of the table view as the `intrinsicContentSize`

Your tableview needs to be an actual subclass in which you override both `contentSize` and `intrinsicContentSize` like this (Note that the contentSize just has an added observer, its not really overridden):

```
override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }
```

Now, when you set up your table view, make sure you set its content compression resistance and content hugging priority to required, then it should size itself within your view automatically based on its intrinsic content size.

Comment: Almost identical answer here, with a little more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48623673/98600